# Probability number A greater number B

Tags: probability-distributions

Given $a \in \{1,2,...,250\}$ and $b \in \{0,1,...,1000\}$

$a$ and $b$ are chosen randomly, how does one calculate the probability of $a > b$?

Comment: I am sorry but this is better suited at math-stacexchange. You should also specify what you mean by "randomly".